# How to set multiple quotas for a single user

Tags: opportunity, forecast, quota

Sales executives sell bikes.
I want to set a quota on sales executives by new and used bikes(to incentivize them).
For example in November Sales executive Rob must sell 5 new and 3 used bikes.

How can I set this up in Salesforce?

I see under forecasting, you can set up quota for users based on quantity, however, how can I set quota using new bike vs used bike?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up forecasting by Product Family. Once you do this, you'll be allowed to forecast per Product Family. In Setup > Object Manager, you'd first configure two families, New and Used (or you can be more specific), then go to Setup > Forecast Settings (use Quick Search), enable forecasting and add a forecast type that uses Product Family, and select the type of forecasting. Finally, you can then go to the user and provide forecast quotas for each Product Family.